# How to split a text at the beginning of a string using Regex.Split?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I tried to split a text with words and the problem is that it splits at the end of string, here is what I tried:

```
string StringFromTheInput = TextBox1.Text;
string[] splichar1 = Regex.Split(StringFromTheInput, @"(?<=(word1|word2|word3|word4|))\s+");
```

- here is what I get from the text after split:

  Text:  sentence word1 blah blahh

Output:  sentence word1

- what I want to get from the Text:

Output: word1 blah blahh

Comment: I tried to use  @"(?=>(    instead of @"(?<=(  but doesn`t work....

Comment: I want to split the text at the start of the word

Comment: Use the **split** operator of string `StringFromTheInput.Split(' ')`